# Reset the content of a CSV file in the file cabinet

Tags: file, netsuite

I'm reading the content of a CSV file in the file cabinet with a user Event Suitelet living on sales orders and trying to reset the content of the file to an empty CSV after I'm done

I can successfully append lines and read the content but nothing about resetting the content in the NetSuite documentation.
I'm just looking for a way to reset the File to an empty CSV.

```
/**
 *
  @NApiVersion 2.x
  @NModuleScope SameAccount
  @NScriptType UserEventScript
  @appliedtorecord salesorder
 */

define(['N/file'], function(file) {
  function resetCSVFile(context) {
    var fileObj = file.load({ id: '104819' });

    var iterator = fileObj.lines.iterator();
    var idArrays = [];

    iterator.each(function(line) {
      idArrays.push(line.value);
      // the line below is my failed attempt at resetting the line
      line.value = ''
      return true;
    });

    log.audit({ title: 'idArrays', details: idArrays });

    fileObj.save();
    return true;
  }

  return {
    afterSubmit: resetCSVFile
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you're done processing the file, you'll want to use `file.create()` to make a new file object with the same `name`, `fileType`, and `folder` property values.  Set the `contents` property of that file object to something (perhaps the header row), and save it.  This will overwrite the existing file with an empty file but **keep the same internal id of the original file**.

Here's an example that captures the header row of the CSV file and creates an empty file with that header row.  When you create a file object, the contents property cannot be null or an empty string.

```
var fileObj = file.load({ id: '5447' });
var currentLine = 0;
var headerRow = '';
fileObj.lines.iterator().each(function(line) {
  currentLine++;
  if (currentLine === 1) {
    headerRow = line.value + '\n';
  }
  log.debug({ title: 'header', details: line.value });
  return true;
});

var newFile = file.create({
  name: fileObj.name,
  fileType: file.Type.CSV,
  folder: fileObj.folder,
  contents: headerRow
});

newFile.save();
```